# Access Denied while uploading document in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to upload document from my local drive to SharePoint. My code is debugging properly but the file is not getting uploaded in SharePoint.

I got this error message:

> Cannot create an item at the requested destination.  Verify that the folder exists and that you have permission to edit in it.

Code:

```
public void  scantosharepoint()
{
    String source = "D:\\sharepoint.pdf";
    String[] destination = { "https://ms-shre2010/Shared Documents/adithyan_folder/" };

    ScanDocumentRef.FieldInformation fieldinfo = new ScanDocumentRef.FieldInformation();
    fieldinfo.DisplayName = "learn about sharepoint";
    fieldinfo.Type = ScanDocumentRef.FieldType.Text;
    fieldinfo.Value = "SharePoint";
    ScanDocumentRef.FieldInformation[] fieldinfoarray = { fieldinfo };
    ScanDocumentRef.CopyResult copyres = new ScanDocumentRef.CopyResult();
    ScanDocumentRef.CopyResult[] copyresarray = { copyres };

    certificat();
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(source, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] fileContents = new byte[stream.Length];
    byte[] r = new Byte[stream.Length];
    int ia = stream.Read(fileContents, 0, Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length));
    stream.Close();
    //String data = Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray);
    //uint getuint = scanDoc.GetItem(source, out fieldinfoarray, out bytearray);

    uint scanresult = scanDoc.CopyIntoItems(source, destination, fieldinfoarray, fileContents, out copyresarray);
}
```

Comment: You say it debugs fine but you get an error message? When do you get the error message? I would be tempted to use GetItem to populate the bytearray as per microsofts remarks, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy.copy.copyintoitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx ... and finally the source URL could be an issue, documentation says "SourceUrl is not used in the copy operation but is stored with the document on the server as the CopySource property. This enables users of the copy to navigate back to the source." which isn't helpful as to what happens if the sourceurl is not in sharepoint.

Comment: Try removing the 'source' from CopyIntoItems, i.e. when creating new content make the source and destination the same... uint scanresult = scanDoc.CopyIntoItems(destination, (string[])destination, fieldinfoarray, fileContents, out copyresarray)

Comment: See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27504/copy-file-to-sharepoint

Comment: How did you get it working?

Comment: i had given folder in destination url as same as source url

Comment: code:  String source = "D:\\bigdata.pdf";
            String[] destination = { "https://ms-shre2010/Shared Documents/adithyan_folder/bigdata.pdf" };